# Read a text file line by line and save each line in the buffer irrespective of data type and length of each line

Tags: c, windows, winapi, text, text-files

I want to read one line of the text file, save it to a buffer, send the buffer over a udp socket and then go and read the second line and so on..

So far, since I knew the data type of the text to be read from the text file, I had been using

> fscanf()

to read each line from the text file. But now I don't know the data types so it is not possible for me to use this function anymore. Is there any other way to read text file line by line.

**Note:** *The length of each line may vary.*

Comment: Why not read any data type as char[] or char* and then parse the relevant data?

Comment: Read one line from a text file using fgets() and stored it in char[] but what I get is corrupted data :(

Comment: Strange. If it would be text data and you'd stored it in a null finished char[], you wouldn't be getting garbage at all...

Comment: @AyeshaHassan `fgets()` keeps the newline at the end of the string as a valid character.Make sure you don't end up with two newlines when you write it back.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture : +1 for pointing that out :)

Comment: If you don't know the format of the file, you can't read it effectively. Is the file encoded as text or binary? Ansi or Unicode? It makes a **BIG** difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a handy code I found to read data as binary

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("c:\\test.bin", "r");
char *x = new char[10]; 
//size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size_of_elements, size_t number_of_elements, FILE      *a_file);
fread(x, sizeof(x[0]), sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]), fp);
```

Comment: `"r"` opens the file in text mode. `"rb"` opens the file in binary mode instead.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the data type you can never know what you're going to read into your variables... Let's see, you mention that the length of each line may vary, right?. So we can assume that your text file contains... text. That is, the the number 128 would not be represented by a single integer, but by three chars that you would read and then parse into an integer.

That said, there's not a lot of options there but to build a parser (you read each line and try to guess what it is based on the chars you've read, say, are there only numbers?, are there only numbers but there's a dot? are there only a-z characters?, are they both?) that would't be 100% reliable or just try to always know the data type beforehand (say, save the first char that you read from each line for the data type when writing the file).

A very different story goes on if your text file is not really in text, but in binary mode. If that's the case... well, there's nothing to do but knowing the data types beforehand.

Comment: I guess file format i.e. ".txt" is defined :(
The data types of the contents inside the file is not known. i.e file may have char as well as int.

Comment: Ayesha: if the file is a .txt file and can be read with your regular notepad application then it probably is in "text mode" as opposed to "binary mode". If your file is in text mode you can think of it like this: when you see 1234 you're not really "reading" the number "1234" but four separate characters being "1", "2", "3" and "4", and then putting them together like this: 1*1000+2*100+3*10+4 => 1234. I am reasonably sure that the file won't be mixing binary stream data with text data, but all will be in text data (thus, enabling you to parse). Can we see the file?. Maybe that'll help.

Comment: +1 for sharing the information. Opening the file in binary mode solved the problem of data corruption :)